# ajax request on html, but express cant get data

Tags: node.js, express

I am submitting a basic html form, but I get `undefined` from the `req.body`. Any help?

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {

  console.dir(req.body, {depth:null});

  console.log(req.body.username)
  console.log(req.body.email)
  console.log(req.body.password)
}
```

LATEST UPDATE:

I even tried to make a basic html form for testing like this on a new file

```html
<form class="" action="register" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="button">submit</button>
</form>
```

Still, I get the `undefined` logged… I am using ejs so the file extensions are `.ejs`.

Comment: Welcome, is it the same address and same port? Which port do you listen to on your express server?

Comment: 8080 @Kolzar maybe it is about that ?

Comment: but i received the request, it prints undefined

Comment: Could you put a screen of request/response on this post?

Comment: I updated @Kolzar

Comment: To have `req.body` filled, you must include a body-parsing middleware like [`express.urlencoded`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded).